# Dealing with Large Bitmaps (tiling a small bitmap to create wallpaper)

Tags: android, memory, view, bitmap

I'm having memory problems and think it might have to do with creating large bitmaps.

The task at hand is to get a fairly small tile image and create a larger tiled image and set this as the phone wallpaper. The way I'm doing this is:

> 1) Create a view that is 2 * screen width, 1 * screen height
>
> 2) Set the view background to a BitmapDrawable with the tile mode set to repeat
>
> 3) Create a bitmap with the views dimensions
>
> 4) draw the view to the bitmap by: view.draw(new Canvas(bitmap))
>
> 5) set wallpper: getApplicationContext().setWallpaper(bitmap)

This works fine on my phone (HTC Magic) and other phones that I have tried. But I am getting bug reports relating to this issue. I tried to recreate the problem by doubling the required dimensions and the problem seems to be happening in the 4th step when the view is being drawn to the bitmap:

> ERROR/dalvikvm-heap(124): Heap Massage needed (7372800-byte external allocation too big)

I'm not sure how to go about solving this. Please help!
Thanks

Comment: Since Android 4.0 there is much better debugging possibility available, since the memory used for bitmap allocation is now correctly listed as memory used in the heap monitor in DDMS. Pre-4.0 the memory used for bitmap allocation was not shown in the heap monitor, so one could have only guessed how much memory is used in reality. Maybe this helps you to better debug your code.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you thought of it, but nevertheless: Have you included

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />
```

in your manifest-file?

You're sure there is no exception thrown? It could possibly be a problem with showing the Toast.

Comment: Yes I have and it works on my phone and various other phones that I have tried it on. In order to replicate the error what I did was make the image larger and It is infact a problem with attempting to allocate too much memory for the bitmap. I'll change the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure if this is your solution, but have you looked at  ? [BitmapFactory.Options.inTempStorage](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inTempStorage)

The way you use it is:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inTempStorage = new byte[16*1024];
Bitmap bitmap_origin = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't think you can do much... We are on a mobile phone here ; Android limis the process memory to 16MB.

Here are a couple of tips and tricks I can give you (because I have the sames issues in my application)

- Are you sure you need 32 bits pixels? that's three 8bit color channels plus a 8bit alpha channel. You can use RGB_565 for a visually acceptable result.
- Recycle the image that you don't need when you create your bitmap (and that you won't need to draw your bitmap)
- `null` any other object that you don't need
- Run [`System.gc()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#gc%28%29) to force a garbage collection just before you create the `Bitmap`

Hope this helps!

Comment: And another tip that is not good here: don't use images larger than needed :-)

Comment: thanks but have already tried all these and still getting issues reported from users every once in a while...maybe your right, it might just be the limitation of a mobile device and just have to optimize everything wherever bitmaps are being used.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you could refactor your code. You'll have better performance and probably use less memory if you don't use a `View`

1. Create a `Bitmap` of the desired size `bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width,height,Bitamp.Config.RGV_565)` (or `ARGB_8888`, that might work too)
2. Create a `canvas = new Canvas(bitmap)`
3. Create the tiled image yourself, from your `src`

simplified Code:

```
// set another matrix if you want rotation/scaling of the input
Matrix identity=new Matrix(); 
for (int i=0; i<maxLines; i++) {
  for (int j=0; j<maxCol; j++) {
    canvas.draw(src, identity,anyPaint);
  }
}
```

Keep the end  set wallpaper `getApplicationContext().setWallpaper(bitmap)`

Comment: thanks just tried this and seems like a good idea. Its just hard to see how much of a difference its making(doubt it would be effecting the memory that much though) as the problem doesn't happen much on my phone in the first place. thanks anyways!

Comment: Also in your code something like identity.setTranslate(patternWidth * i,patternHeight * j) would have to be added before every draw call.